# Determine whether each of the given sets is a subspace of the indicated vector space and, if so, find the dimension

Tags: matrices

Determine whether each of the given sets is a subspace of the indicated vector space and, if so, find the dimension

a) Does the set of all 2x2 matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$ constitute a subspace of all $M_{2x2}$?

b) Consider the set of all functions of the form $y=ax^2$. Is this a subspace of $P_2$?

c) Is the set of all vectors of the form (x, 1, z) a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Unfortunately I don't understand the question. The answers according to the professor are:

a) Yes, dimension 3.

b) Yes, dimension 1.

c) No. The set is not closed under addition.

I do have a handout that lists the ten axioms for vector spaces, but that's all I have at the moment. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Edit: The handout also lists a definition of vector space V, and then subset H which adheres to three properties. In question a, would V be $M_{2x2}$ and H be $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$ and we need to check if it follows those three properties? I still wouldn't understand how to get the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is a subspace of $V$ if (I) $0 \in S$ and (II) for all $u, v \in S$ and $\alpha, \beta \in K$, we have $\alpha v + \beta u \in S$.

Now, $(c)$ fails property (I).

(b) The zero polynomial satisfies the condition and so (I) holds and if $f, g \in S$ and $\alpha, \beta \in K$, then $\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) = \alpha a x^{2} + \beta a x^{2} = a (\alpha  + \beta) x^{2} = cx^{2} \in S$.

Hence, $S$ is a subspace. $\{x^{2} \}$ is linearly independent ($\{1, x, x^{2} \}$ is a basis of $V = P_{2}$) and it also spans $S$. This is why $S$ has dimension 1.

For (a), just check the criterion the same way we did in part (b). Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix that has zero everywhere except 1 at position (ij).

Now note that if $A$ is a matrix in $H$, then $A = a E_{11} + bE_{12} + cE_{21}$. Also the set $\{E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}\}$ is linearly independent so that this is a basis for $H$.